# Calling Axios API hit in a service file from Reducer Giving Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

In react I am trying to make a "Rest API call via Axios". I made a service file and then when reducer is trying to console.log the output of the service. it is giving error. Please help.

**someReducer.js**

```
import getItemsAPI from '../../services/service1';

...

case "GET_ITEM_LIST": {
    let data = getItemsAPI.getItems();
    console.log(data);
    return {
        ...state,
        items: data
    }
}
```

**service1.js**

```
class getItemsAPI {

    getItems() {
      return this.axiosInstance
        .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
        .then((response) => response.data);
    }

  }

export default getItemsAPI;
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a `class`, you must use the `new` keyword in order to create an instance.  Then, you can use its methods:

```
import getItemsAPI from '../../services/service1';
const getItemsInstance = new getItemsApi();

...

case "GET_ITEM_LIST": {
    let data = getItemsInstance.getItems();
    console.log(data);
    return {
        ...state,
        items: data
    }
}
```

You don't *need* to use a `class` in order to export a function.  You can export the function itself (in this case, inside an object):

```
const getItemsAPI = {

    getItems: () => {
      return axiosInstance
        .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
        .then((response) => response.data);
    }

  }

export default getItemsAPI;
```

If you use the code above, you don't need to create an instance.  You can simply use the object (like your doing in the OP).

Just a note as well.  `getItems` will return a `Promise`. In order to get data, you must `await` or resolve the `Promise` before reducing.

Comment: Hi, I tried same but now in service1.js in which you are sending function as property of object I am getting error --- "TypeError: Cannot read property 'axiosInstance' of undefined" for the line where you have written return statement.

Comment: You have no `this` outside a class.  I made an edit.  I don't know how you are importing `axiosInstance`.